# Is there an adblock like addon to block links in facebook

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, facebook

So there is a lot of pages that i like , But they are very annoying with their links to useless blogs with misleading titles and pictures like this
[one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ynDj.jpg)

And I almost always fall for them even though i know i don't need to read them and they are a waste of my time , So i was wondering is there an Addon for firefox (like Adblock plus) that hide the link posts from that page that i liked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB Purity comes close. It's not really a adblock but it does clean a lot of crap from facebook.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fb-purity-clean-up-facebo/ncdlagniojmheiklojdcpdaeepochckl?hl=en

Comment: good enough for me